# How to color only one row of a grid?

Tags: c#, xaml, grid, windows-store-apps

I'm creating small browser as user control. I want to colour only one row because i'm moving address bar to bottom of grid. I tried to change `Background` in `RowDefinitions` but there isn't such property in XAML.

So how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct, you are not supposed to set a background in RowDefinitions. 
You could for example use a **Grid** to do that.

Here is a small example:

```
    <Grid>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>

      <Grid Grid.Row="0"
          Background="AliceBlue" />
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Glad to help. :) You can also use other controls than a Grid to set the color.

Comment: Yes, I know. I my case I'd use ```Canvas``` for color change